# How to install thunderbird 31.4 on centos7

Tags: centos, thunderbird

I'm trying to install the thunderbird 31.4 on centos7.

What I done:

1. Downloaded from that link: [Thunderbird Page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/download)
2. tar -xvjf .....
3. cd thunderbird; ./thunderbird

The error:

```
bash: ./thunderbird: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Than; I installed that 32 bits lib's:

4. yum -y install glibc.i686
5. trying to run the ./thunderbird again...

New error:

```
./thunderbird: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Than, I installed these shared library missing

6. yum install libstdc++.i686
7. trying to run the ./thunderbird again......

New error:

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/thunderbird/libxul.so:
libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

So I've installed these packages (finding the libs of erros with yum whatprovides)

```
yum install libXrender-0.9.8-2.1.el7.i686
yum install alsa-lib-1.0.27.2-3.el7.i686
yum install dbus-glib-0.100-7.el7.i686
```

and than, I've tryied to execute the thunderbird again, and new error:

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/thunderbird/libxul.so:
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or irectory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

So I run:

```
yum whatprovides libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

than trying to install what provides these lib:

```
 yum install gtk2-2.24.22-5.el7.i686
```

Get these error on the yum:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
   cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
   pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

     1. You have an upgrade for gtk2 which is missing some
        dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
        solve this by installing an older version of gtk2 of the
        different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
        yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
        requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
        --exclude gtk2.otherarch ... this should give you an error
        message showing the root cause of the problem.

     2. You have multiple architectures of gtk2 installed, but
        yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
        If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
        can remove the one with the missing update and everything
        will work.

     3. You have duplicate versions of gtk2 installed already.
        You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).

   Protected multilib versions: gtk2-2.24.22-5.el7.i686 != gtk2-2.24.22-5.el7_0.1.x86_64
```

Comment: Does /lib/ld-linux.so.2 exist?
Is the architecture of the libraries x86/amd64 matching the downloaded version?

The downloads seem to be 32 bit. If you are on a 64 bit distribution, you will need to install 32bit libs, google for ia32libs

Comment: Yes my friend, for that reason I already downloaded the 32 bits in iten 4 of my question

Comment: Libraries: plural

https://www.aleach.com/libstdc-so-6-error-in-centos-6/ - It shows you how to use `yum whatprovides`

Comment: @ChristianBock Thank you very much. I will find these packages and if I solve this, by your comment, I will let you know to you post an answer to I accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was:

I installed all these 32 bits packages:

```
yum -y install glibc.i686  libstdc++.i686 libXrender-0.9.8-2.1.el7.i686 alsa-lib-1.0.27.2-3.el7.i686 dbus-glib-0.100-7.el7.i686 gtk2.i686 libXt-1.1.4-6.1.el7.i686
```

I changed the gtk2-2.24.22-5.el7.i686 package to the gtk2.i686 to do not get this error of conflicting lib's.

The answer of Christian Bock: I think it could resolve too that issue of installing thunderbird 31.4 on CentOS7, but only these packages here are required to run the thunderbird.

The comment of Christian Bock; also helps to resolve these issue, by seeing what package provides the library:

```
yum whatprovides libraryName
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to install Thunderbird on CentOS 7 (I found):

```
su
yum install epel-release
yum search thunderbird
yum install thunderbird.(which ever version listed suits your platform)
```

epel-release is the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux, and contains the latest Thunderbird (31.4 today)

Thunderbird listed here:
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS/repoview/applications.internet.group.html

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install libXrender.i686
```

For further missing libraries, try

```
yum whatprovides <filename>
```

You most probably want to install the most common 32 bit libraries, usually referred as ia32libs by invoking

```
yum -y install --skip-broken glibc.i686 arts.i686 audiofile.i686 bzip2-libs.i686 cairo.i686 cyrus-sasl-lib.i686 dbus-libs.i686 directfb.i686 esound-libs.i686 fltk.i686 freeglut.i686 gtk2.i686 hal-libs.i686 imlib.i686 lcms-libs.i686 lesstif.i686 libacl.i686 libao.i686 libattr.i686 libcap.i686 libdrm.i686 libexif.i686 libgnomecanvas.i686 libICE.i686 libieee1284.i686 libsigc++20.i686 libSM.i686 libtool-ltdl.i686 libusb.i686 libwmf.i686 libwmf-lite.i686 libX11.i686 libXau.i686 libXaw.i686 libXcomposite.i686 libXdamage.i686 libXdmcp.i686 libXext.i686 libXfixes.i686 libxkbfile.i686 libxml2.i686 libXmu.i686 libXp.i686 libXpm.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 libxslt.i686 libXt.i686 libXtst.i686 libXv.i686 libXxf86vm.i686 lzo.i686 mesa-libGL.i686 mesa-libGLU.i686 nas-libs.i686 nss_ldap.i686 cdk.i686 openldap.i686 pam.i686 popt.i686 pulseaudio-libs.i686 sane-backends-libs-gphoto2.i686 sane-backends-libs.i686 SDL.i686 svgalib.i686 unixODBC.i686 zlib.i686 compat-expat1.i686 compat-libstdc++-33.i686 openal-soft.i686 alsa-oss-libs.i686 redhat-lsb.i686 alsa-plugins-pulseaudio.i686 alsa-plugins-oss.i686 alsa-lib.i686 nspluginwrapper.i686 libXv.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 qt.i686 qt-x11.i686 pulseaudio-libs.i686 pulseaudio-libs-glib2.i686 alsa-plugins-pulseaudio.i686
```

Comment: I used these command from you and installed the packages, but I've got new error installing a new package, I edited in the question the news. tnxs

Comment: Editing the question in a way so the answers don't reflect it anymore is discouraged. Question and answer are no longer related and worthless for future visitors.

For your attempt at solving this issue, I suggest you refer to the centos IRC channel http://wiki.centos.org/irc

Comment: My edition reflects because I do not miss the issue here, only edited with adding more information about the problem. Your suggestion to go to centos irc channel breaks the purpose of these forum, who is the location to resolve exactly this kinds of issue.

Comment: This is not a forum.

Comment: I will not discuss the concept of the word "forum" here. Its abstraction and a point of view